# How to log terminal keystrokes in ubuntu

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I want to log whatever is happening in my terminal in a text file . I want to save all session information in the log file. We can do this in putty. But I dont know how to achieve the same in simple terminal in ubuntu.  Also, is it possible to use putty to open a terminal for localhost? I tried doing that . But does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can record your terminal session (assuming you're using Bash) by doing `script`.

You probably want `script -k` which records input *and* output.

So in all, doing something like `script -k logfilename` you will get what you want!

Comment: I tried script -k logfile. It did not work. I am using bash shell. Looks like -k is not the option for me. So I used script -a logfile and it worked. Thanks @Travis.